# cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-14411

Tags: python, sql, oracle, oracle11g, cx-oracle

I ran an `ALTER TABLE` query to add some columns to a table and then `db.commit()`. That didn't raise any error or warning but in Oracle SQL developer the new columns don't show up on `SELECT * ...`.

So I tried to rerun the `ALTER TABLE` but it raised

`cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-14411: The DDL cannot be run concurrently with other DDLs`

That kinda makes sense (I can't create columns that already exist) but when I try to fill the new column with values, I get a message

`SQL Error: ORA-00904: "M0010": invalid ID
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`

which suggests that the new column has **not** been created yet.

Does anybody understand what may be going on?

**UPDATE/SOLVED** I kept trying to run the queries another couple of times and at some point, things suddenly started working (for no apparent reason). Maybe processing time? Would be weird because the queries are ultra light. I'll get back to this if it happens again.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't need commit, DDL effectively commits any transaction.

[Ora-14411 means](http://ora-14411.db.quanti.cz/)

> Another conflicting DDL was already running.

so it seems that your first ALTER TABLE statement hasn't finished yet (probably table is too big, or some other issues).

Comment: you seem to be right, see my update. Still weird, the table has only 33 rows, 11 columns...